# How to calculate a hash of a Tx?

Tags: transactions, protocol, hash, algorithms

How does one calculate the hash of a Tx? Which fields need to be double SHA hashed and in what order?

Comment: Do you mean the transaction ID hash that the JSON-RPC send* methods return? It can be confusing because hashes for transactions are calculated and signed to transmit bitcoins, but the hashes that are signed are NOT the same as the transaction ID hashes....

Comment: I mean the hashes calculated for the merkle tree, but I suppose both would be useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As explained by [Gavin Andersen on the forum](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=54451.msg649253#msg649253) - in order to calculate the ID hash of the Tx that is used in the Merkle Tree, one needs to SHA hash [the whole Tx message](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_specification#tx) as defined in [the Protocol Specification wiki page](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_specification#tx) twice.

For example, for the only Tx from the [Genesis Block](http://blockexplorer.com/block/000000000019d6689c085ae165831e934ff763ae46a2a6c172b3f1b60a8ce26f) one would double hash the following array of bytes:

01000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000FFFFFFFF4D04FFFF001D0104455468652054696D65732030332F4A616E2F32303039204368616E63656C6C6F72206F6E206272696E6B206F66207365636F6E64206261696C6F757420666F722062616E6B73FFFFFFFF0100F2052A01000000434104678AFDB0FE5548271967F1A67130B7105CD6A828E03909A67962E0EA1F61DEB649F6BC3F4CEF38C4F35504E51EC112DE5C384DF7BA0B8D578A4C702B6BF11D5FAC00000000

And if double hashed correctly, it would give the following hash:

[4A5E1E4BAAB89F3A32518A88C31BC87F618F76673E2CC77AB2127B7AFDEDA33B](http://blockexplorer.com/tx/4a5e1e4baab89f3a32518a88c31bc87f618f76673e2cc77ab2127b7afdeda33b)

Comment: Little endian! In most implementations that double-hash would yield `3b a3 ed fd 7a 7b 12 b2 7a c7 2c 3e 67 76 8f 61 7f c8 1b c3 88 8a 51 32 3a 9f b8 aa 4b 1e 5e 4a`, but you'll want to reverse that: `4a 5e 1e 4b aa b8 9f 3a 32 51 8a 88 c3 1b c8 7f 61 8f 76 67 3e 2c c7 7a b2 12 7b 7a fd ed a3 3b`, resulting in the actual hash that is *actually* used.

Comment: Thanks, here's my php implementation: `function getTransactionHash($transaction_in_hex)
{
    $bin = hex2bin($transaction_in_hex);
    $hash = hex2bin(hash('sha256', hex2bin(hash('sha256', $bin))));
    return bin2hex(strrev($hash));
}`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a python implementation to find the doubleSHA256 hash for genesis block:

```
01000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000FFFFFFFF4D04FFFF001D0104455468652054696D65732030332F4A616E2F32303039204368616E63656C6C6F72206F6E206272696E6B206F66207365636F6E64206261696C6F757420666F722062616E6B73FFFFFFFF0100F2052A01000000434104678AFDB0FE5548271967F1A67130B7105CD6A828E03909A67962E0EA1F61DEB649F6BC3F4CEF38C4F35504E51EC112DE5C384DF7BA0B8D578A4C702B6BF11D5FAC00000000

import codecs

//switch the endianness of a given string
def revEndian(string):
    return ''.join(reversed([string[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(string), 2)]))

//convert a bytebuffer into a string
def hashStr(bytebuffer):
    return str(codecs.encode(bytebuffer, 'hex'))[2:-1]

//find the double sha256 hash for a given hex string
def doubleSha256(hex): 
    bin = codecs.decode(hex, 'hex')
    hash = hashlib.sha256(bin).digest()
    hash2 = hashlib.sha256(hash).digest()
    return revEndian(hashStr(hash2))
```

Comment: How is hex computed from the transaction?

Answer (score -3):

There's a diagram explaining the process of hashing a transaction when creating or verifying the signature of a bitcoin transaction on [the forum](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=29416.msg370321#msg370321), and a higher resolution version of the same image on [dropbox](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1139081/BitcoinImg/OpCheckSigDiagram.png).

Comment: This image is now dead and the links do not work. This is why you are supposed to POST THE IMAGE not links to an image.