# How are transaction hashes calculated?

Tags: transactions, hash, encoding

I'm trying to calculate the hash of transactions in bitcoin blocks, but I'm not getting the right answers.

For example, the [genesis block has a single transaction](http://blockexplorer.com/b/0).

Here's how I'm attempting to calculate its hash...

Transactions are encoded as:

- a 32 bit 'nVersion'
- a list of input transactions, vin
- a list of output transactions, vout
- a 32 bit 'nLockTime'

For the transaction in the genesis block, these are:

- nVersion: `01000000`
- inputs

  - count: `01`
  - 1st input:

    - prevout_hash: `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`
    - prevout_n: `ffffffff`
    - scriptSig: `4d`:`04ffff001d0104455468652054696d65732030332f4a616e2f32303039204368616e63656c6c6f72206f6e206272696e6b206f66207365636f6e64206261696c6f757420666f722062616e6b73`
    - sequence: ffffffff
- outputs

  - count: `01`
  - 1st output:

    - value: `00f2052a01000000` (hex(50*10^8) is 0000012a05f200, and bitcoin puts the bytes in reverse order)
    - scriptPubKey: `43`:`4104678afdb0fe5548271967f1a67130b7105cd6a828e03909a67962e0ea1f61deb649f6bc3f4cef38c4f35504e51ec112de5c384df7ba0b8d578a4c702b6bf11d5fac`
- nLockTime: `00000000`

If I string all those together end to end, I get 204 bytes: `01000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffff4d04ffff001d0104455468652054696d65732030332f4a616e2f32303039204368616e63656c6c6f72206f6e206272696e6b206f66207365636f6e64206261696c6f757420666f722062616e6b73ffffffff0100f2052a01000000434104678afdb0fe5548271967f1a67130b7105cd6a828e03909a67962e0ea1f61deb649f6bc3f4cef38c4f35504e51ec112de5c384df7ba0b8d578a4c702b6bf11d5fac00000000`

Taking the sha256 hash of this gives `27362e66e032c731c1c8519f43063fe0e5d070db1c0c3552bb04afa18a31c6bf`.

Taking the sha256 hash of that hash gives `3ba3edfd7a7b12b27ac72c3e67768f617fc81bc3888a51323a9fb8aa4b1e5e4a`.

But the real transaction hash according to blockexplorer.com is `4a5e1e4baab89f3a32518a88c31bc87f618f76673e2cc77ab2127b7afdeda33b`.

What am I doing wrong?  How can I get to the correct transaction hash?

Here's my working in Python:

```
>>> import Crypto.Hash.SHA256 as hash, binascii
>>> tx = '01000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffff4d04ffff001d0104455468652054696d65732030332f4a616e2f32303039204368616e63656c6c6f72206f6e206272696e6b206f66207365636f6e64206261696c6f757420666f722062616e6b73ffffffff0100f2052a01000000434104678afdb0fe5548271967f1a67130b7105cd6a828e03909a67962e0ea1f61deb649f6bc3f4cef38c4f35504e51ec112de5c384df7ba0b8d578a4c702b6bf11d5fac00000000'
>>> len(binascii.unhexlify(tx))
204
>>> hash.new(binascii.unhexlify(tx)).digest().encode('hex_codec')
'27362e66e032c731c1c8519f43063fe0e5d070db1c0c3552bb04afa18a31c6bf'
>>> hash.new(hash.new(binascii.unhexlify(tx)).digest()).digest().encode('hex_codec')
'3ba3edfd7a7b12b27ac72c3e67768f617fc81bc3888a51323a9fb8aa4b1e5e4a'
```

Comment: This is nearly a dup of http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2177/how-to-calculate-a-hash-of-a-tx

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> Taking the sha256 hash of that hash gives
>
> `3b a3 ed fd 7a 7b ..............`
>
> But the real transaction hash according to blockexplorer.com is
>
> `.............. 7b 7a fd ed a3 3b`

The answer I was getting was correct, but bytewise reversed.  I need to get used to Bitcoin using little-endian storage.

Comment: I found the answer to my own question shortly after asking it.  Should I delete the question and the answer or leave them both?

Comment: It's a valid question, it's a correct answer and you did the work to find it. I'd give it a few days to make sure someone doesn't post a more complete (or awesome) answer and then just accept your own answer. Ideally it's not the way StackExchange works, but it's perfectly valid to self-answer - trust me you're not a trend-setter on this one ;)

Comment: Actually, it is encouraged to post and share your own answer, when applicable.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: You just saved me so many hours of research . i was facing exactly the same issue. cheers