# Are transaction ids always the same length?

Tags: protocol, transaction-id, specification

Do all bitcoin transaction ids (hashes) have the same length?

I guess it's defined somewhere here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_specification but still I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. The transaction ID is SHA256(SHA256(transaction)) as described [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2177/how-to-calculate-a-hash-of-a-tx) and thus always has a length of 256 bits (32 bytes).