# Meaning/Derivation of 32 byte TxID hash

Tags: transactions, protocol

A largely abstract question (set) I've tried to answer for awhile is the nature of a TxID (32 byte hex Transaction ID hash).

First and foremost, I certainly understand the main function if this value(?) is to *uniquely identify a Transaction* (primarily to tracks unspent outputs, AKA UTXOs).

But let's take a random TxID, say [*e151de4f5a339ed545e24ecfc8f811f9143fefc10574af40721a156ff2d3a389*](https://blockchain.info/tx/e151de4f5a339ed545e24ecfc8f811f9143fefc10574af40721a156ff2d3a389).

1. How is a TxID assigned to a Transaction?
2. Are 2 identical Txs that: double spend, have identical *k* PRNG-signed (so not a RNG!) sigs, identical inputs/outputs (a lot of assumptions here) given identical hashes?
3. Tangentially: are the Big/Little Endian expressions of TxIDs (by [BCI](http://blockchain.info) and bitcoincore respectively) suggesting two different usages (ie TxIDs are values in one sense but akin to URIs in another: is this normal?)

I know the questions seem somewhat disparate but I think the best summation is **what *exactly* are TxIDs?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How is a TxID assigned to a Transaction?

It's a hash of key transaction information -- inputs, outputs, scripts, signatures.

> Are 2 identical Txs that: double spend, have identical k PRNG-signed (so not a RNG!) sigs, identical inputs/outputs (a lot of assumptions here) given identical hashes?

This question is ill-formed. Unless there's some difference between them, they're not 2 transactions, they're one transaction. It's like talking about "two identical integers" -- that would just be one integer.

Comment: To clarify: a Tx formed from identical components except the signature will have different hashes, correct? How does one calculate the Tx hash from a raw Tx exactly? (ie is it a double SHA256 of the raw Tx with(out) appended SIGHASH?)

Comment: Yes, different signatures means a different transaction. It's not quite as simple as hashing the raw transaction. See [this link](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/2233/85).